# Detect rotated strings

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

Read two strings from `stdin`.
Output `Yes` if one string is a rotated version of the other.
Otherwise output `No`

**Testcases**

Input

```
CodeGolf GolfCode
```

Output

```
Yes
```

Input

```
stackexchange changestackex
```

Output

```
Yes
```

Input

```
stackexchange changestack
```

Output

```
No
```

Input

```
Hello World
```

Output

```
No
```

Comment: So (*abcdefAB*, *ABabcdef*) is a "YES"?

Comment: Should it really be a rotation or is a combination fine too? eg. what will `Stackexchange Stackchangeex` return?

Comment: @Eelvex, yes. @jpjacobs, It would return `No`. The rotation is a shift, like those LED scrolling signs

Comment: Are the strings always whitespace-free and separated by whitespace?

Comment: More specifically, what characters are allowed in those strings?

Comment: Originally I was intending two strings of non-whitespace separated by whitespace, but I see people are doing hacks with regex. That's cool as long as the test cases pass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### APL (28)

Takes input on two lines.

```
'No' 'Yes'[1+(⊂⍞)∊⌽∘A¨⍳⍴A←⍞]
```

Explanation:

- `A←⍞`: read a line of input and store it in A
- `⌽∘A¨⍳⍴A`: Rotate A by x, for each x in [1..length A]. Gives a list, i.e. `estT stTe tTes Test`
- `(⊂⍞)∊`: read another line of input, and see if it is in this list.
- `1+`: add one to this, giving 1 if the strings were not rotated and 2 if they were
- `'No' 'Yes'[`...`]`: Select either the first or second element from the list `'No' 'Yes'` depending on whether the strings were rotated or not.
- This value is output automatically.

Answer (score 19):

### Ruby <strike>49</strike> 41

```
a,b=$*;puts (a*2).sub(b,'')==a ?:yes: :no
```

Edit: replaced gets.split by $*

Comment: That's an ingenious idea.

Comment: Very clever. :)

Comment: `$*` is argv when the question specified `stdin` though.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 70 bytes

```
a,b=raw_input().split()
print ['No','Yes'][a in b*2and len(a)==len(b)]
```

[Testing ...](http://ideone.com/sMtVR)

Comment: +1 Nice, selecting the result from an array is clever! :-)

Comment: The question states you should read two strings from `stdin`, which this solution does not.

Comment: @Ventero:Fixed.

Comment: You can skip the space in `print ['No`

Answer (score 6):

**Python 70 Characters**

```
a,b=raw_input().split()
print'YNeos'[len(a)<>len(b)or a not in 2*b::2]
```

Thanks to gnibbler for the slice trick.

Comment: Same problem as the GolfScript solution: If you input `nn nfn`, you get `Yes`, which is wrong.

Comment: @TomWij Thanks for finding the bug. Corrected. Should work now.

Comment: You can replace `<>` by `-` as that will also result in `0` if they are of equal length.

Comment: But what if they are not of equal length?
Then it doesn't work so well :-)

Comment: @hallvabo then the strings are not rotated version of each other.

Comment: Yes of course, but the output will be wrong too, since the slicing trick only works with 0 or 1, not an arbitrary integer...

Comment: @hallvabo I am sorry I did not understand your point at first. Thanks for finding that. I have updated the solution.

Comment: I think python3 would be slightly shorter

Answer (score 5):

### J, 47

```
y=:>2{ARGV
(>1{ARGV e.1|.^:(i.#y)y){'No',:'Yes'
```

Comment: Why the two J answers?

Comment: @JB: because this one uses the buildin rotate. Both answers su^H^H are not so good btw. There is a *lot* of room for golfing.

Comment: why the other one, then, I'm tempted to ask? :-)

Comment: @JB: because I thought this one is barely legal ( :p ) [ while the other one extends nicely to lisp. ]

Comment: errr... the other one seems to read input from the command-line as well

Answer (score 5):

According to the spec (same string lengths):

#### Perl, <strike>42</strike> 43 chars

```
$.=pop;$_=(pop)x2;print+(qw'yes no')[!/$./]
```

If different sized strings are allowed, the solution would be:

#### Perl, 47 chars

```
$.=(pop)x8;$_=(pop)x9;print+(qw'yes no')[!/$./]
```

rbo

Comment: Same problem as the GolfScript solution: If you input `nn nfn`, you get `Yes`, which is wrong.

Comment: seems to be ok (I missed the'!' in the first version)

"nn nfn" => **no**

"CodeGolf GolfCode"
 => **yes**

Answer (score 5):

### Golfscript, 31

```
' '/:)~,\,=)~.+\/,(&'Yes''No'if
```

This one check length first, so it should work as expected.

Comment: `:)` and `=)` +1 for very happy code

Answer (score 4):

### J, 57

```
{&('No';'Yes')@-:/@:((/:~@(|."0 _~i.&$))&.>)&.(;:&stdin)_
```

Sample use:

```
$ echo -n CodeGolf GolfCode | jconsole rotate.ijs
Yes
$ echo -n stackexchange changestackex | jconsole rotate.ijs
Yes
$ echo -n stackexchange changestack | jconsole rotate.ijs
No
$ echo -n Hello World | jconsole rotate.ijs
No
```

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, 76

```
$a,$b=-split$input
('No','Yes')[+!($a.length-$b.length)*"$b$b".contains($a)]
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 51

```
function f(a,b)a&&(a+a).replace(b,"")==a?"Yes":"No"
```

JavaScript doesn't have a canonical host, so this answer is written as a function of two arguments.  The score goes up to 60 if we disallow JS 1.7 features (expression closures).

In the SpiderMonkey shell this would be (for a score of 71):

```
[a,b]=readline().split(" ");print(a&&(a+a).replace(b,"")==a?"Yes":"No")
```

Comment: 5 years later and now you can use the `=>` function notation ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Python, <strike>66</strike> 63

```
a,b=raw_input().split()
print'YNeos'[a!=(2*a).replace(b,"")::2]
```

**Another solution in 69 char**

```
a,b=raw_input().split()
print['No','Yes'][a in b*2and len(a)==len(b)]
```

Comment: `print'YNeos'[a!=(2*a).replace(b,"")::2]`

Comment: @gnibbler nice trick, thanks for suggestion. I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

### J, 84

```
y=:(>1{ARGV),:(>2{ARGV)
((0{y)e.(y&((]$0{[),(]-~[:}.[:$[)$1{[)/.i.}.$y)){'No',:'Yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 71

```
a,b=raw_input().split()
print'Yes'if a in b*2and len(a)==len(b)else'No'
```

Comment: Same problem as the GolfScript solution: If you input `nn nfn`, you get `Yes`, which is wrong.

Comment: Problem has been solved, remains low... :-)

Comment: Doesn't read from stdin as specified.

Comment: Now it does... :-)

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript (120 chars)**

```
function f(a,b) {for (i=0,A=a.split("");A.join("")!=b&&i++<a.length;A.push(A.shift()));return A.join("")==b?'Yes':'No';}
```

Output:

```
f('CodeGolf','GolfCode'); //Yes
f('stackexchange','changestackex'); //Yes
f('stackexchange','changestack'); //No
f('Hello','World'); //No
f('nn','nBn'); //No
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 58 (62) characters

```
a,b=gets.split;$><<(a.size==b.size&&/#{a}/=~b*2?:Yes: :No)
```

This solution assumes the input contains only alphanumeric characters (actually everything that doesn't have a special meaning inside a regular expression is ok).

A solution that doesn't have this constraint is 4 characters longer

```
a,b=gets.split;$><<(a.size==b.size&&(b*2).index(a)?:Yes: :No)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (<strike>98</strike> 96 chars)

```
g x y@(t:r)(z:w)|x==y="Yes"|1>0=g x(r++[t])w
g _ _[]="No"
f(x:y:_)=g x y y
main=interact$f.words
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 61

```
<?echo preg_match('/^(.+)(.*) \\2\\1$/',fgets(STDIN))?Yes:No;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 41

```
puts gets =~ /^(.+)(.*) \2\1$/ ?:Yes: :No
```

Comment: Doesn't print anything, results in ':No' for input 'aaa aaa' (on my machine). The regexp approach could be a good idea though.

Comment: Fix to actually print and input from stdin instead of args: `puts gets =~ /^(.+)(.*) \2\1$/ ?:Yes: :No` - ups it to 41 chars.

Answer (score 2):

## Q (<s>50</s> 43 chars)

```
{`No`Yes x in((!)(#)y)rotate\:y}." "vs(0:)0
```

Answer (score 2):

### bash 56

```
read a b
[[ $a$a =~ $b&&$b$b =~ $a ]]&&echo Yes||echo No
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scala 78**

```
val b=readLine split " "
print(b(0).size==b(1).size&&(b(0)+b(0)contains b(1)))
```

It's a shame about the size check, without it the count drops to **54**

```
val a=readLine split " "
print(a(0)+a(0)contains a(1))
```

Comment: `"""val b=readLine split " " print(b(0).sorted==b(1).sorted)""".length` yields 56

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 25 bytes

```
' '/~.2*@/''+='Yes''No'if
```

#### How it works

```
             # STACK: "CodeGolf GolfCode"
' '/         # Split input string by spaces.
             # STACK: [ "CodeGolf" "GolfCode" ]
~            # Dump the array.
             # STACK: "CodeGolf" "GolfCode"
.            # Duplicate the topmost string.
             # STACK: "CodeGolf" "GolfCode" "GolfCode"
2*           # Repeat the topmost string.
             # STACK: "CodeGolf" "GolfCode" "GolfCodeGolfCode"
@            # Rotate the three topmost strings.
             # STACK: "GolfCode" "GolfCodeGolfCode" "CodeGolf"
/            # Split the second topmost string around the topmost one.
             # STACK: "GolfCode" [ "Golf" "Code" ]
''+          # Flatten the array of strings.
             # STACK: "GolfCode" "GolfCode"
=            # Check for equality.
             # STACK: 1
'Yes''No'if  # Push 'Yes' for 1, 'No' for 0.
             # STACK: "Yes"
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 21 bytes

```
r]r_,,\f{\{(+}*}_@+^!
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r_%2C%2C%5Cf%7B%5C%7B(%2B%7D*%7D_%5Br%5D%2B%5E!&input=golfcode%20codsgolf)

Comment: [This answer](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyi2KF5HJyatOqZaQ7tWqzbeQTtO8f9/5/yUVPf8nDSuNCgLAA) seems to return `0`/`1` instead of `No`/`Yes`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
ɠṙJɠeị“Yes“No
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///kgoc7Z3qdXJD6cHf3o4Y5kanFQNIv//9/5/yUVPf8nDQuEAHiAAA)

### How it works

```
ɠṙJɠeị“Yes“No - Main link. Takes no arguments
ɠ             - Read a line from STDIN
  J           - Indices; [1, 2, ..., len(S)]
 ṙ            - All rotations of S
   ɠe         - Read a line from STDIN; is that in the rotations?
     ị“Yes“No - Index that into ["Yes", "No"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

Not sure about the rules here, Husk doesn't do IO at all. The closest alternative is a function:

```
!w¨Ye∫No¨€U¡ṙ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X7H80IrI1Ecdq/3yD6141LQm9NDChztnGv7//985PyXVPT8n7T@IAHEA)

#### Explanation

```
!w¨Ye∫No¨€U¡ṙ1
           ¡    -- iterate the following for ever:
            ṙ1  --   rotate string by 1
          U     -- only keep the longest prefix with unique elements
         €      -- is the argument in that list?
  ¨Ye∫No¨       -- compressed string: "Yes No"
 w              -- split on space
!               -- modular index (1-based)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Lua 115 chars**

```
a,b=io.read():match"(%w+) (%w+)"c=b repeat c=c:sub(2,-1)..c:sub(1,1) s=s or a==c until b==c print(s and"Yes"or"No")
```

Answer (score 1):

### C program - 146

```
char b[99],c[99],*p,*q;main(n){q=(p=b+(n=strlen(gets(c))))+n;sprintf(b,"%s%s"
,c,c);for(gets(c);p>b&&strcmp(p,c);--p,*--q=0);puts(p>b?"Yes":"No");}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 82 characters

```
<?$s=split(" ",fgets(STDIN));echo str_replace($s[1],"",$s[0].$s[0])==$s[0]?Yes:No;
```

Answer (score 1):

**perl, 123 chars**

```
@s1=split(//,shift);
$s2=shift;
$i=0;
while($i<=@s1){
    if(join("",@s1) eq $s2){die "yes";}
    unshift @s1,pop @s1;
    $i++;
}
die "no";
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <strike>30</strike> 37

```
gets
puts~/^(.+)(.*) \2\1$/?:Yes: :No
```

A version that prints "true" and "false" instead of "yes" and "no":

```
gets
p !! ~/^(.+)(.*) \2\1$/
```

Both of these work with different-length strings (unlike the old one)

Comment: Does work if the two strings have the same length, but fails on input like 'golfcode golf'.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 86 Characters

```
a,b=raw_input().split()
print"Yes"if any(a==b[n:]+b[:n]for n in range(len(a)))else"No"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed to say Yes/No and improved (91 chars)

```
import List;f[a,b]|a`elem`[x++y|x<-tails b|y<-inits b]="Yes";f _="No";main=interact$f.words
```

original Haskell (92 chars) that says True/False

```
import Data.List;f(a:b:_)=any(a==)$zipWith(++)(tails b)(inits b);main=interact(show.f.words)
```

Comment: You can save a few characters with `import List` and also by using `$` instead of parens around the argument to `interact`.  But your program outputs `True` and `False` instead of the required `Yes` and `No`, so that might take a few extra chars to fix.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl (just a quick fix)

A fix to rubber boots' solution, being a new user that I am I can't comment yet so I'll just post a new answer.

As the mentioned method uses a regular expression constructed from user input, it is possible to perform a small regex injection, as follows:

```
> perl -le '$.=pop;$_=(pop)x2;print+(qw/yes no/)[!/$./]' anything '.*'
yes
```

The fix is to use \Q (known also as quotemeta):

```
> perl -le '$.=pop;$_=(pop)x2;print+(qw/yes no/)[!/\Q$./]' anything '.*'
no
```

The code itself could be further shortened using 'say' but this is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Furthermore, instead of `print+(qw/yes no/)[` you can probably write `print qw(yes no)[` which is two characters shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 95

The function `rotated?` simply tests one string against all possible rotations of the other. Brute force.

```
(defn rotated?
  [a b]
  (let[l (count a)
       b (seq b)]
    (->> a cycle (partition l 1) (take l) (some #{b}))))
```

I personally don't care where the input strings come from, but if it has to be stdin...

```
(apply rotated? (.split (read-line) " "))
```

This would add 38 to character count, if strings were whitespace separated.

```
(rotated? (read-line) (read-line))
```

This would add 32 to character count, if strings were newline separated. The function `rotated?` works with any characters in the strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <strike>70</strike> <strike>65</strike> <strike>59</strike> 55 characters

new approach:

```
read a b;c=$a$a;[[ ${c/$b/} == $a ]]&&echo yes||echo no
```

Comment: solution 2 fails on `echo ofofo fofof | bash rotated.sh` - doesn't it? Else I would remove even more WS: `read a b[[ $a$a =~ $b&&${#a}-eq${#b} ]]&& echo yes||echo no`. I had a very similar idea, and think it works.

Comment: You're right, more ws can be removed, and the paratheses! Need a `;` after the read tho.

Comment: @userunknown - hah, got'cha ;)

Comment: You can remove a blank before and one behind `==`.

Comment: I tried, but then it always return 'yes'.

Comment: You're right. So my test was wrong. Have to verify my own solution isn't wrongly tested too... - ok: verified.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript - 66

```
p=prompt,a=p(),b=p();alert(!b.match(a)&&!!b+b.match(a)?'Yes':'No')
```

Comment: 1) This says True for “foo” and “foot”. 2) The output has to be “Yes” or “No”. The other participants spent great amount of code to produce the required output. Please do so.

Comment: Is the problem true/false or that 'foo' is not a rotation of 'foot'?

Comment: 1) Giving wrong result for “foo” and “foot”, is a bug. 2) Producing different output then required, is just deviation. Many answers fail to conform with the requirements in various degrees – some got downvoted, others not. Is up to you to decide whether you risk some downvotes or correct them.

Comment: Should be working now.

Comment: Much better. It gives “Yes” for “foo” and “.*”, but as the question owner still not replied to the [comment about allowed characters](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/detect-rotated-strings/12883?noredirect=1#comment2428_1364), let us suppose that only the character classed used in the samples are allowed.

Comment: @manatwork, Oops, dunno how I missed that for so long. I've replied to it now :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

Code:

```
DgFÀD²Qi"Yes",q}}"No
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RGdGw4BEwrJRaSJZZXMiLHF9fSJObw&input=Q29kZUdvbGYKR29sZkNvZGU)

Comment: The builtins and features of 05AB1E have improved quite a bit over the years. :) [13 bytes is now possible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196108/52210)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ɠJṙ@€ɠe@ị“Yes“No
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///kAq@HO2c6PGpac3JBqsPD3d2PGuZEphYDSb/8//@d81NS3fNz0rhABIgDAA)

Many thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing and @MrXcoder for helping me out in chat.

Explanation:

```
ɠ                   # The first string
  ṙ@€               # Rotated by...
 J                  #   The indexes of each element in the string
     ɠ              # The second string
      e@            # Exists in that list of strings.
                    # (either '0' or '1')
        ị           # Indexed into the list...
         “Yes“No    # ["yes", "no"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>118</s> <s>113</s> 111 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
i,l,r;f(s,t)char*s,*t;{for(l=r=0,i=strlen(s);i--;)r=strncmp(s+i,t,++l)|strncmp(s,t+l,i)?r:3;puts(r+"No\0Yes");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY67CgIxEEVr/QpJlZhZEOwMi4WFVrYi2Cwxq8HZZJmJIKjfHo2v2mruPfcUY6uDtTl7QCDTSoak7LGhMcM4mWsbSWJN9QR8zYnQBcnK@KoyigoItuslaw8JtEZ1@yFIGsGrOc2mpj8nlqTFOu4mW8dCmXv2IY26xgephtfhoJViEfduGbEVMBLllv40Xxunxp7c5flXOLgivNMH/2N9nZVDjGXbRMJ9off8AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -Rn, 62 + 4 = 65 bytes

```
len('if[inputs|explode|sort|implode]|.[0]==.[1]then"Yes"else"No"end')
```

As in the accepted answer, the two strings should be on separate lines. `-R` is used to avoid having to quote the input strings, and `-n` is used to disable the default input processing because `inputs` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ä:∩ö┌┘/YJTI
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8e3aef94dad92f594a5449&i=CodeGolf%0AGolfCode%0A%0Astackexchange%0Achangestackex%0A%0Astackexchange%0Achangestack%0A%0AHello%0AWorld&a=1&m=1)

This program takes input on two lines.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
:(      get all rotations
s|#     other input is a member of rotations?
`n!`    "Yes"
.No     "No"
?       (a ? b : c)
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3A%28%09get+all+rotations%0As%7C%23%09other+input+is+a+member+of+rotations%3F%0A%60n%21%60%09%22Yes%22%0A.No%09%22No%22%0A%3F%09%28a+%3F+b+%3A+c%29&i=CodeGolf%0AGolfCode%0A%0Astackexchange%0Achangestackex%0A%0Astackexchange%0Achangestack%0A%0AHello%0AWorld&m=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā._Êßi„Noë”…Ü
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNe/OGuw/MzHzXM88s/vPpRw9xHDcsOz/n/3zk/JdU9PyeNC0SAOAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVqns8qhhmYKawuG99koKj9omKSjZJ/w/0qgXf7jr8PzMRw3z/PIPr37UMBeo6vCc/0DGoW3etTr/nfNTUt3zc9IUQASIw1VckpicnVqRnJGYl56qAKGgYrjluDxSc3LyFcLzi3JSAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā         # Push a list in the range [0, length] for the (implicit) input-string,
          # without popping this input-string itself
          #  i.e. "CodeGolf" → [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
 ._       # Rotate the string that many times towards the left (vectorized)
          #  "CodeGolf" and [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] → ["olfCodeG","lfCodeGo","fCodeGol","CodeGolf",
          #                                      "odeGolfC","deGolfCo","eGolfCod","GolfCode"]
   Ê      # Check for each whether it's NOT equal to the second (implicit) input-string
          #  "GolfCode" → [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
    ß     # Pop and push the minimum (to check if any are falsey)
          #  [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] → 0 (falsey)
     i    # If this minimum is truthy (so all rotations were unequal to the second input):
      „No #  Push string "No"
     ë    # Else:
      ”…Ü #  Push dictionary string "Yes"
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”…Ü` is `"Yes"`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 57 bytes

Input via space-delimited string on `STDIN`, output to `STDOUT` is `"Yes"` or `"No"` string.

```php
<?=strpos(($a=explode(' ',$argn))[1].$a[1],$a[0])?Yes:No;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSoIL9YQ0Ml0Ta1oiAnPyVVQ11BXUclsSg9T1Mz2jBWTyURSAIFog1iNe0jU4ut/PKt//93Bqp0z89JUwARIM6//IKSzPy84v@6bgA)

Or with [Default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) input via command line args and output `truthy`/`falsey`.

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```php
<?=strpos(($a=$argv)[2].$a[2],$a[1]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSoIL9YQ0Ml0VYlsSi9TDPaKFZPJRFI6gBJw1hN6////zvnp6S65@ek/QcRIA4A)

Or as a function:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
function($a,$b){return strpos($b.$b,$a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9BSwMxEIXP5lcMJbC7EEXPa/FQqj0I9uZhXUo2nZjWJROSFITSv25MdNerp5n3vjfwxhmX7h@ccYxHDDHAEjp21VUr2uMTjboSVRlFVr0oJESpPvBTGWnfMePfZXL/z0yJDY4jZfJKftwXr28Z43qZ9MmqeCBbcyn40Jw9xpO3EKJ3FGo@3PBBcNm0l5QPNHmUykANU3sZ8gYNnBkAKkNwDGR3aFXuX/8gAYu3uBDAddHdbS/KuOsL2W62u/XLc8suaf4f5u//nDQ7X@RK0ZCuH78B)

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WMVpHJVFHJSnWViWxKL1Mp7ikqCC/WEMlSU8lCSijaf3//3/n/JRU9/yctP8gAsQBAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY8xa8MwFITn6lc8gsA2qCWZXadDaJuhEG8dHBNkWarSGj1haQiE/vWqUmJnzfTu3XfDndU2PL9YbQn10nkHFTTkock22Mt3HFTGsnTSm7UsEee5@JEnobn5khFfxeTez0yJrRwGjOQTx6FPXlsSQlUVlMkpZ7QrqrXzo0WX0@6JdozyIsSIwlFyoSGHqS93UUEBZwIghUb4dmgO0ojYOL8gBou9XzCgKv3NsmXprNpE6m19eN19lOQ3zIth3ntzwuz8ofVHNC48vv0D "PHP – Try It Online") using PHP 7.4 arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

## [K3 / Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 28

```
{:[y _in![;x]'!#x;`Yes;`No]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
?}zm.<QdlQ"YES""NO
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%7Dzm.%3CQdlQ%22YES%22%22NO&input=%22CodeGolf%22%0AGolfCode&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
?}zm.<QdlQ"YES""NO
   m   dlQ            For each number in [1, ..., len(first input)]...
    .<Q               ... rotate the first input that many characters.
 }z                   Check if the second input is in that list.
?         "YES""NO    Return "YES" or "NO" appropriately.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
~c₂ᵐ↔ᵈ∧"Yes"|∧"No
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wvy4ZxNk64VHblIdbOx51LFeKTC1WqgEx/PL//49WiFZyzk9Jdc/PSVPSUQJRIK5SrE60UnFJYnJ2akVyRmJeeipQEsKAihJSAZb3SM3JyQeKh@cX5aSARRKTklNAKlNBDBSRxOQkmL2JuSABMBWrEAsA)

(If the input strictly has to be whitespace-separated, add two bytes to prepend `ṇ₁`, but note that the input still has to be quoted. Brachylog does not have any sort of direct access to stdin.)

Takes input as a list of two strings, and outputs through the output variable. The actual logic is all in the first six bytes, which succeed if the elements of the input are rotations of each other, and fail if they are not:

```
   ᵐ      Both strings in the input
~c₂       can be split into two pieces each
    ↔ᵈ    such that one string's two chunks are the other's swapped.
```

(`↔ᵈ` could just as well be `pᵈ`, `pᵛ`, or `oᵛ` which is what it was originally before I decided that `↔ᵈ` is more to the point.)

Although it would be possible to brute force rotating one of them until it matches, the number of rotations would need to be explicitly bounded, and on top of that just the effort required to separate out the two elements of the input list would be fairly costly. Since it's very easy to brute force partitions in Brachylog, the fact that a rotation is just as much taking one chunk off one end and moving it to the other as it is doing that to single characters however many times saves a lot of bytes.

With very flexible I/O, this could be as short as 5 bytes, taking one string through the input variable and the other through the output variable: [`~c₂↔c`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaHWzsedSxXKikqTdVT0nvUsUIpLTGnGMiufbirs/bh1gn/65IfNTU9apuS/P9/tEK0knN@Sqp7fk6ako4SiAJxlWJ1opWKSxKTs1MrkjMS89JTgZIQBlSUkAqwvEdqTk4@UDw8vygnBSySmJScAlKZCmKgiCQmJ8HsTcwFCYCpWIVYAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ż€ẒQM"YesNo"½i
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNSVCQyVFMiU4MiVBQyVFMSVCQSU5MlFNJTIyWWVzTm8lMjIlQzIlQkRpJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9Q29kZUdvbGYlMEFHb2xmQ29kZSZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
ż€ẒQM"YesNo"½i  # Implicit input
ż€Ẓ             # All rotations of the first input
   QM           # Is the second input NOT in it?
     "YesNo"½   # Push the list ["Yes", "No"]
             i  # Index the result into it
                # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 55 bytes

```perl6
->\a,\b {my@a=a.comb;grep {b eq@a.rotate($_).join},^@a}
```

Returns a list of rotate positions that produce a match, which is truthy when non-empty.

If you have to output `Yes` or `No`, then the following takes 66 bytes:

```perl6
->\a,\b {my@a=a.comb;<No Yes>[?grep {b eq@a.rotate($_).join},^@a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7X9cuJlEnJkmhOrfSIdE2US85PzfJOr0otUChOkkhtdAhUa8ovySxJFVDJV5TLys/M69WJ84hsfa/NVdxYqVCmoaSc35Kqnt@TpqSjoISiAbxlTTh0sUlicnZqRXJGYl56akgNRAWVJhIhUjKPFJzcvJB0uH5RTkpQIn/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 28 bytes

```
(;:'No Yes'){::~[e.#\@]|."{]
```

Takes in input via function arguments.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxR8PaSt0vXyEytVhds9rKqi46VU85xiG2Rk-pOhai5OY8Ta7U5Ix8BXXn_JRU9_ycNHWFNAV1EAMkoA6VLC5JTM5OrUjOSMxLTwWrgDCh4kQpgynySM3JyQdLhucX5aTAhBOTklNS0xydwDKOThCuOsSVCxZAaAA)

```
(;:'No Yes'){::~[e.#\@]|."{]­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
                           ]  NB. ‎⁡right arg
                   #\@]       NB. ‎⁢take the right arg then get the length of each prefix [1..len(y)]
                       |."{   NB. ‎⁣rotate the right by each element of the left, obtain all rotations
                [e.           NB. ‎⁤is the left arg a member of the resulting table?
(;:'No Yes')                  NB. ‎⁢⁡split the string, returns an array of boxed strings
            {::~              NB. ‎⁢⁢fetch using the boolen result of e., unlike {, this unboxes the result
```